# What design pattern does jQuery use for its style of get/set methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

Is there a name for the pattern that jQuery uses for its style of get & set methods? Specifically the way that the method's behaviour changes depending on whether an argument is passed or not.

For example:

```
$('#my-element').text(); // Gets the text from #my-element
$('#my-element').text('Hello there') ;// Sets the text of #my-element
```

Thanks!

Edit: I guess I'm asking not really how it works, but if there's a formal pattern for how it's done.

Comment: function overloading :P

Answer (score 0):

It is the concept of `method overloading` used in various functions from jquery library created by john resig.

Javascript has capability to have different return types for overloaded function.

Same things goes for `.text()` here. Based on arguments it is decided that which function needs to be executed.

1)**Returns String**

```
$('#my-element').text(); // Gets the text from #my-element
```

2)**Return Jquery Object**

```
$('#my-element').text('Hello there') ;// Sets the text of #my-element
```